# C2011 'CMemDC':'class' type redefinition in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, mfc

First of all, I would like you to know that the code that I'm using are the same codes that can be found in GitHub. Second, I have tried various solutions online such as setting header blocks or placing `#pragma once` on top of the cpp file, but still produce the same errors to be mentioned below.

What I'm confused about is how this code is found in various repositories, but I can't build it using VS 2019.

My guess is that I need to install VS 2010 for this to build properly, but I'm considering it as a last resort to solve this problem.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

#### TextProgressCtrl.cpp

```cpp
// TextProgressCtrl.cpp : implementation file
//
// Written by Chris Maunder (chrismaunder@codeguru.com)
// Copyright 1998.
//
// Modified : 26/05/98 Jeremy Davis, jmd@jvf.co.uk
//              Added colour routines
//
// TextProgressCtrl is a drop-in replacement for the standard 
// CProgressCtrl that displays text in a progress control.
//
// This code may be used in compiled form in any way you desire. This
// file may be redistributed by any means PROVIDING it is not sold for
// profit without the authors written consent, and providing that this
// notice and the authors name is included. If the source code in 
// this file is used in any commercial application then an email to
// the me would be nice.
//
// This file is provided "as is" with no expressed or implied warranty.
// The author accepts no liability if it causes any damage to your
// computer, causes your pet cat to fall ill, increases baldness or
// makes you car start emitting strange noises when you start it up.
//
// Expect bugs.
// 
// Please use and enjoy. Please let me know of any bugs/mods/improvements 
// that you have found/implemented and I will fix/incorporate them into this
// file. 
#ifndef _MEMDC_H_        // changed location from original code
#define _MEMDC_H_        // added for header blocks
#include "stdAfx.h"
#include "TextProgressCtrl.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif



//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CMemDC - memory DC
//
// Author: Keith Rule
// Email:  keithr@europa.com
// Copyright 1996-1997, Keith Rule
//
// You may freely use or modify this code provided this
// Copyright is included in all derived versions.
//
// History - 10/3/97 Fixed scrolling bug.
//                   Added print support.
//
// This class implements a memory Device Context

class CMemDC : public CDC
{
public:

    // constructor sets up the memory DC
    CMemDC(CDC* pDC) : CDC()
    {
        ASSERT(pDC != NULL);

        m_pDC = pDC;
        m_pOldBitmap = NULL;
        m_bMemDC = !pDC->IsPrinting();

        if (m_bMemDC)    // Create a Memory DC
        {
            pDC->GetClipBox(&m_rect);
            CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
            m_bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC, m_rect.Width(), m_rect.Height());
            m_pOldBitmap = SelectObject(&m_bitmap);
            SetWindowOrg(m_rect.left, m_rect.top);
        }
        else        // Make a copy of the relevent parts of the current DC for printing
        {
            m_bPrinting = pDC->m_bPrinting;
            m_hDC = pDC->m_hDC;
            m_hAttribDC = pDC->m_hAttribDC;
        }
    }

    // Destructor copies the contents of the mem DC to the original DC
    ~CMemDC()
    {
        if (m_bMemDC)
        {
            // Copy the offscreen bitmap onto the screen.
            m_pDC->BitBlt(m_rect.left, m_rect.top, m_rect.Width(), m_rect.Height(),
                this, m_rect.left, m_rect.top, SRCCOPY);

            //Swap back the original bitmap.
            SelectObject(m_pOldBitmap);
        }
        else {
            // All we need to do is replace the DC with an illegal value,
            // this keeps us from accidently deleting the handles associated with
            // the CDC that was passed to the constructor.
            m_hDC = m_hAttribDC = NULL;
        }
    }

    // Allow usage as a pointer
    CMemDC* operator->() { return this; }

    // Allow usage as a pointer
    operator CMemDC* () { return this; }

private:
    CBitmap  m_bitmap;      // Offscreen bitmap
    CBitmap* m_pOldBitmap;  // bitmap originally found in CMemDC
    CDC* m_pDC;         // Saves CDC passed in constructor
    CRect    m_rect;        // Rectangle of drawing area.
    BOOL     m_bMemDC;      // TRUE if CDC really is a Memory DC.
};

#endif



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CTextProgressCtrl

CTextProgressCtrl::CTextProgressCtrl()
{
    m_nPos = 0;
    m_nStepSize = 1;
    m_nMax = 100;
    m_nMin = 0;
    m_bShowText = TRUE;
    m_strText.Empty();
    m_colFore = ::GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT);
    m_colBk = ::GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW);
    m_colTextFore = ::GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT);
    m_colTextBk = ::GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW);

    m_nBarWidth = -1;
}

CTextProgressCtrl::~CTextProgressCtrl()
{
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTextProgressCtrl, CProgressCtrl)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CTextProgressCtrl)
    ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_SIZE()
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_SETTEXT, OnSetText)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_GETTEXT, OnGetText)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CTextProgressCtrl message handlers

LRESULT CTextProgressCtrl::OnSetText(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPCTSTR szText = (LPCTSTR)lParam;
    LRESULT result = Default();

    if ((!szText && m_strText.GetLength()) ||
        (szText && (m_strText != szText)))
    {
        m_strText = szText;
        Invalidate();
    }

    return result;
}

LRESULT CTextProgressCtrl::OnGetText(WPARAM cchTextMax, LPARAM szText)
{
    if (!_tcsncpy((LPTSTR)szText, m_strText, cchTextMax))
        return 0;
    else
        return min(cchTextMax, (UINT)m_strText.GetLength());
}

BOOL CTextProgressCtrl::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* /*pDC*/)
{
    return TRUE;
}

void CTextProgressCtrl::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CProgressCtrl::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    m_nBarWidth = -1;   // Force update if SetPos called
}

void CTextProgressCtrl::OnPaint()
{
    if (m_nMin >= m_nMax)
        return;

    CRect LeftRect, RightRect, ClientRect;
    GetClientRect(ClientRect);

    double Fraction = (double)(m_nPos - m_nMin) / ((double)(m_nMax - m_nMin));

    CPaintDC PaintDC(this); // device context for painting
    CMemDC dc(&PaintDC);
    //CPaintDC dc(this);    // device context for painting (if not double buffering)

    LeftRect = RightRect = ClientRect;

    LeftRect.right = LeftRect.left + (int)((LeftRect.right - LeftRect.left) * Fraction);
    dc.FillSolidRect(LeftRect, m_colFore);

    RightRect.left = LeftRect.right;
    dc.FillSolidRect(RightRect, m_colBk);

    if (m_bShowText)
    {
        CString str;
        if (m_strText.GetLength())
        {
            if (m_strText.ReverseFind(L'%') < 0)
            {
                str.Format(_T("%s (%d %%)"), m_strText, (int)(Fraction * 100.0));
            }
            else
            {
                str = m_strText;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            str.Format(_T("%d%%"), (int)(Fraction * 100.0));
        }

        dc.SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);

        CRgn rgn;
        rgn.CreateRectRgn(LeftRect.left, LeftRect.top, LeftRect.right, LeftRect.bottom);
        dc.SelectClipRgn(&rgn);
        dc.SetTextColor(m_colTextBk);

        dc.DrawText(str, ClientRect, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);

        rgn.DeleteObject();
        rgn.CreateRectRgn(RightRect.left, RightRect.top, RightRect.right, RightRect.bottom);
        dc.SelectClipRgn(&rgn);
        dc.SetTextColor(m_colTextFore);

        dc.DrawText(str, ClientRect, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);
    }
}

void CTextProgressCtrl::SetForeColour(COLORREF col)
{
    m_colFore = col;
}

void CTextProgressCtrl::SetBkColour(COLORREF col)
{
    m_colBk = col;
}

void CTextProgressCtrl::SetTextForeColour(COLORREF col)
{
    m_colTextFore = col;
}

void CTextProgressCtrl::SetTextBkColour(COLORREF col)
{
    m_colTextBk = col;
}

COLORREF CTextProgressCtrl::GetForeColour()
{
    return m_colFore;
}

COLORREF CTextProgressCtrl::GetBkColour()
{
    return m_colBk;
}

COLORREF CTextProgressCtrl::GetTextForeColour()
{
    return m_colTextFore;
}

COLORREF CTextProgressCtrl::GetTextBkColour()
{
    return m_colTextBk;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CTextProgressCtrl message handlers

void CTextProgressCtrl::SetShowText(BOOL bShow)
{
    if (::IsWindow(m_hWnd) && m_bShowText != bShow)
        Invalidate();

    m_bShowText = bShow;
}


void CTextProgressCtrl::SetRange(int nLower, int nUpper)
{
    m_nMax = nUpper;
    m_nMin = nLower;
}

int CTextProgressCtrl::SetPos(int nPos)
{
    if (!::IsWindow(m_hWnd))
        return -1;

    int nOldPos = m_nPos;
    m_nPos = nPos;

    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(rect);

    double Fraction = (double)(m_nPos - m_nMin) / ((double)(m_nMax - m_nMin));
    int nBarWidth = (int)(Fraction * rect.Width());

    if (nBarWidth != m_nBarWidth)
    {
        m_nBarWidth = nBarWidth;
        RedrawWindow();
    }

    return nOldPos;
}

int CTextProgressCtrl::StepIt()
{
    return SetPos(m_nPos + m_nStepSize);
}

int CTextProgressCtrl::OffsetPos(int nPos)
{
    return SetPos(m_nPos + nPos);
}

int CTextProgressCtrl::SetStep(int nStep)
{
    int nOldStep = m_nStepSize;
    m_nStepSize = nStep;
    return nOldStep;
}
```

#### TextProgressCtrl.h

```
#if !defined(AFX_TEXTPROGRESSCTRL_H__4C78DBBE_EFB6_11D1_AB14_203E25000000__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_TEXTPROGRESSCTRL_H__4C78DBBE_EFB6_11D1_AB14_203E25000000__INCLUDED_

#if _MSC_VER >= 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER >= 1000

// TextProgressCtrl.h : header file
//
// Written by Chris Maunder (chrismaunder@codeguru.com)
// Copyright 1998.
//
// Modified : 26/05/98 Jeremy Davis, jmd@jvf.co.uk
//              Added colour routines
//
// TextProgressCtrl is a drop-in replacement for the standard 
// CProgressCtrl that displays text in a progress control.
//
// This code may be used in compiled form in any way you desire. This
// file may be redistributed by any means PROVIDING it is not sold for
// profit without the authors written consent, and providing that this
// notice and the authors name is included. If the source code in 
// this file is used in any commercial application then an email to
// the me would be nice.
//
// This file is provided "as is" with no expressed or implied warranty.
// The author accepts no liability if it causes any damage to your
// computer, causes your pet cat to fall ill, increases baldness or
// makes you car start emitting strange noises when you start it up.
//
// Expect bugs.
// 
// Please use and enjoy. Please let me know of any bugs/mods/improvements 
// that you have found/implemented and I will fix/incorporate them into this
// file. 

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CTextProgressCtrl window

class CTextProgressCtrl : public CProgressCtrl
{
// Construction
public:
    CTextProgressCtrl();

// Attributes
public:

// Operations
public:
    int         SetPos(int nPos);
    int         StepIt();
    void        SetRange(int nLower, int nUpper);
    int         OffsetPos(int nPos);
    int         SetStep(int nStep);
    void        SetForeColour(COLORREF col);
    void        SetBkColour(COLORREF col);
    void        SetTextForeColour(COLORREF col);
    void        SetTextBkColour(COLORREF col);
    COLORREF    GetForeColour();
    COLORREF    GetBkColour();
    COLORREF    GetTextForeColour();
    COLORREF    GetTextBkColour();

    void        SetShowText(BOOL bShow);

// Overrides
    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CTextProgressCtrl)
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

// Implementation
public:
    virtual ~CTextProgressCtrl();

    // Generated message map functions
protected:
    int         m_nPos, 
                m_nStepSize, 
                m_nMax, 
                m_nMin;
    CString     m_strText;
    BOOL        m_bShowText;
    int         m_nBarWidth;
    COLORREF    m_colFore,
                m_colBk,
                m_colTextFore,
                m_colTextBk;

    //{{AFX_MSG(CTextProgressCtrl)
    afx_msg BOOL OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC);
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg void OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy);
    //}}AFX_MSG
    afx_msg LRESULT OnSetText(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    afx_msg LRESULT OnGetText(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//{{AFX_INSERT_LOCATION}}
// Microsoft Developer Studio will insert additional declarations immediately before the previous line.

#endif // !defined(AFX_TEXTPROGRESSCTRL_H__4C78DBBE_EFB6_11D1_AB14_203E25000000__INCLUDED_)
```

#### Errors found

```
C2011 'CMemDC': 'class' type redefinition
'dc' uses undefined class 'CMemDC'
'initializing': cannot convert from 'CPaintDC*' to 'int'
```

Comment: Change `CMemDC ` to `CMyMemDC` and try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CMemDC` class you're referencing originates in an old [codeproject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33/Flicker-Free-Drawing-In-MFC), and predates the `CMemDC` class built into later versions of MFC. So there is a conflict because of the same named classes.

You certainly don't need to install an older Visual Studio to build the example, but you do need to somehow reconcile the conflict. Two ways of doing so are:

1. Modify the example code and rename the `CMemDC` class to something else.
2. Modify the example code and wrap up the unofficial class in a namespace.

e.g (2).

```
namespace CodeProject
{
    class CMemDc : public CDC
    { 
    ...
    };
}
```

and qualify the ocurrence of it

```
CodeProject::CMemDC dc(&PaintDC);
```

Comment: If this is a header-only library, `namespace CodeProject { #include "memdc.h" }` might work, without you having to modify external library files.

Comment: Can't they just comment out the `CMemDC` class as defined in the GitHub code and then it will just use the inbuilt version of MFC?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Probably, and it would certainly build that way, but I wouldn't know if there is a pertinent side effect that the `TextProgressCtrl` demo relies on. Or put another way, we don't know for sure if the one is a drop-in replacement for the other.